# Opera not handling Ajax patch request properly on rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, opera

I'm having issues with submitting data to Rails app from Opera browser. Chrome, Firefox, Safari and IE all seems to be working, but Opera is failing at PATCH request.

My script is:

```
var sendForm = function(type){
  if (type == "POST")
    var url = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + '/account/surveys/' + $('#survey-id').val() + '/respond';
  else
    var url = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + '/account/surveys/' + $('#survey-id').val() + '/respond_upd';

  $.ajax({
      type : type,
      url :  url,
      dataType: 'json',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      data : JSON.stringify({
        "survey": {
        "id": $('#survey-id').val(),
        "survey_answers_attributes": responses(),
        "user_qualities_attributes": serializeQualities()
      }
      })
    });
};
```

So POST and PATCH are using pretty much the same thing, just targeted at different urls.

Now POST works fine, I get it all working and Rails log shows following params:

```
parameters: {"survey"=>{"id"=>"66", "survey_answers_attributes"=>[{"question_id"=>"1", "response"=>"Don't know", "survey_id"=>"66", "user_id"=>"155"}, {"question_id"=>"2", "response"=>"Don't know", "survey_id"=>"66", "user_id"=>"155"}, {"question_i....
```

PATCH however results in params like that:
parameters: {"id"=>"66", "survey"=>{}}

Any idea what might be happening here? This issue is killing me